# Merge json files - Concatenate into a single dict json file

Tags: json, jq

here are 3 JSON files

File1

```
{
  "component1": [
  ]
}
```

File2

```
{
  "component2": [
  ]
}
```

File3

```
{
  "component3": [
  ]
}
```

Don't find the jq command line that would give this JSON file as jq output:

```
{
  "components": {
     "component1": [
      ],
     "component2": [
      ],
     "component3": [
      ]
   }
}
```

Many thanks for your support
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the input objects one a time from `inputs` and append it to the `components` using the `reduce` function

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $d (.; .components += $d )' file{1..3}.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `add`, e.g.

```
jq -s '{components: add}' file{1..3}.json
```

or:

```
jq -n '{components: [inputs]|add}' file{1..3}.json
```